# How to cite indirect sources in CSE/CBE (name–year) system?

Tags: citation-style

I’m writing my first review paper and I don’t know much about the CSE system. I couldn’t find the indirect citation rule for CSE (but for others). So how do I cite indirectly in this style?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by "indirect citation" citing a source cited in another document (which you, most likely, cannot access for some reason) then your citation would be for example:

> (Rawls 1971, cited in Brown 2008)

See [the CSE style guide](http://www.mcgill.ca/library/sites/mcgill.ca.library/files/cse-name-year-citation-style-guide.pdf) for more information.
Anyway, I would strongly encourage you to find the original source and to avoid indirect, secondary citations as you do not know whether the citation is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Yes, I want the thing you mentioned. (So it is same as APA system!)
The thing is, in all the review papers they give the references which becomes indirect source for me and so, I can't find any independent source to cite.

Comment: If you find a useful reference in a review paper, get thee to a library (or a web browser), track down the original paper, and read it yourself.  At that point, it becomes a primary reference.

Comment: @R Blazer @Redwana Blazer If this is the answer you were looking, you can mark it as "accepted answer". Do you need to know more?