# How do I cite a dataset from a database (Datastream)?

Tags: citations, data

I have some data that originally is from OECD, but downloaded from the database Datastream. How do I cite this kind of data? I don’t even know the original name of the dataset, just what it’s called in Datastream, which is not necessarily the same thing, right? And what year do I put down?

Edit: Someone edited my title. The original source is not unknown as is clear from the text. I just can't find the data on the OECD website.

Edit2: The topics linked are not about citing third-party databases, which is what I would like an example of. For example, do I call the dataset what it's called in Datastream or do I need to find the original source and find its name? That doesn't seem possible in this case.

Comment: Regarding your clarification: So, you essentially have the problem of secondary citations with a dataset? Then please take a look at these related questions: [1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11787/7734), [2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7768/7734), [3](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/36452/7734). If they do not fully solve your problem (which I expect), please [edit] your question to focus on what issues aren’t solved.

Answer (score 3):

A question similar to mine with a satisfying answer can be found here: http://libanswers.brunel.ac.uk/faq/49262

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Dataverse](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/), the [Harvard](https://harvard.edu/)'s sharing platform to archive and get credit for your data. The platform creates a [DOI](https://www.doi.org/) that you can cite for.